# Error: undefined reference to QQuickRectangle::QQuickRectangle(QQuickItem*)

Tags: qt, qmake

I want to use Qt Quick 2 directly from C++ without those qml/javascript stuffs that could slows down the app, but i got compilation error when using `QQuickRectangle` (`Rectangle` when used from qml).

In **.pro** file i have: `QT += quick quick-private core-private gui-private declarative-private qml-private`

and in **.cpp** file - `#include <private/qquickrectangle_p.h>`

I compiled the Qt 5.5 from sources and the command `nm -D /usr/local/Qt-5.5.0/lib/libQt5Quick.so.5 | grep "Rectangle"`
doesn't print anything related to `QQuickRectangle`, so it looks that it is not included in the shared library, but i don't know why, because the **qquickrectangle.cpp** exists in qt sources, so it should be included in the shared library after compilation.

Comment: You can't do that. You have to use QML. QML is mostly some memory overhead, it will not slow down you app, you can still use threads and C++ for the performance critical sections, QML is just for UI.

Comment: @ddriver: it isn't true that you can't use Qt Quick directly. Actually i am already doing this, but you need to use private headers and that can lead to compatibility problems with another Qt version, but i will keep my Qt Quick fork with sync, so it is not problem for me and i will have similiar workflow as with Qt widgets. For big complex applications the QML isn't the way i think, but the Scene Graph from Qt Quick is amazing.

Comment: What you try to do is very backward and any efficiency gains will likely be far offset by drawbacks. Last time I checked, nobody has proven QML unfit for big complex applications. The advantages of rapid prototyping and dynamism are simply unavailable with C++. All in all, QML will cost you like 10-15 mb of ram usage. And save you a lot more worth of time and effort, which are far more expensive than ram. The CPU overhead is there but is negligible. You still can and SHOULD write your core and critical sections in C++.

Comment: @ddriver: In QML you have no way to draw just what is visible based on height. If i will implement Project Explorer (hundreds items) in C++, than i can restrict what should be processed based on available height and item height. Another thing is that instead of QQuickItem instance for every item, i can have just one QQuickItem instance and assemble the QSG tree in updatePaintNode directly using QSG nodes. I actually found in mailing list that QML is not good for big desktop applications, Qt developer said that it is intended for applications on embedded devices. I will try to find it.

Comment: This is simply not true. You can wrap your project explorer in a model and use a stock or easily make your own custom view, and it will only render the stuff that is actually visible, and cache elements around the extremes so they don't appear midway when you start scrolling. I have a project which renders hundreds of thousands of nodes in a custom tree structure, and the nodes are like 50 different UIs nested inside one another and it all runs just fine. He said she said, people say all kinds of stuff, I myself am NOT a huge QML fan, but after 2 years of using I'd say it is OK.

Comment: Yes, there were some quirks, some design decisions inside QtQuick that I did not find ideal, but even walking around those things is a minor inconvenience compared to the time QML saves. I actually have custom nodes, which are generated from the "primitive" or built in nodes, so I can get new and unique elements on the go, without compilation. You simply cannot do that with C++. Not without deploying a full QML build and compiler toolchain along with your application, which is simply not possible on a mobile device, and a major inconvenience even for a client's desktop.

Comment: @ddriver: you can do via C++ everything that is possible with QML because the QML is just wrapper. If i want custom node generated from those primitives, i can just instance QQuickItem and add QQuickRectangle, QQuickText,... as childs. I browsed the source code for 2 days now and found Qt Quick 2 is  really good framework for building fast complex UI (but not sure this will be true with QML). I want good framework for very complex IDE and desktop environment using wayland. I am not sure i should go with QML and than fail.

Comment: C++ is a lot slower to develop in to begin with, and using QtQuick with C++ is even more tedious, as the C++ code actually vastly exceeds the size of the QML code. Just take a look at a simple QML element put through the QtQuick compiler to produce C++ code. On top of that, the code is a mess, ugly and illegible. QML is not simply a wrapper, it is a driver, an assist and a great time saver, as even simple few lines of QML code results in a wall of C++ code. And dynamism without recompilation is simply not possible in C++. With QML it is effortless.

Comment: If you think that you are likely to fail trying to use QML, you are in for a treat, as the odds for you to fail trying to use QtQuick with C++ are astronomically higher. If you want to stick to C++, stick to QtWidgets. You will just lose a lot more time and go through a lot more headaches before you realize this is a dead end. QtQuick was not designed to be used with C++ as a public API, which sucks I know, but that's how it is. You will lose every advantage and gain practically nothing. It will be easier to implement your own scene graph if that's all you care about.

Comment: @ddriver: for me the C++ code of Qt Quick 2 looks quite readable, as i saw it is maintained by few people, so i am fine to keep my fork in sync with what they will do. After 2 days i have good idea how it works and now i think if i need modern fast hw accelerated gui, the Qt Quick 2 is best library to use, because the Scene Graph is optimalized for gui where meshes has +- 50 vertices. I will try that QML, but i think it will be hard to implement complex parts of GUI i need.

Comment: @ddriver: first thing i need is to have window splited to arbitrary count of non-overlapping areas that could be resized via splitter handle and the content of any area should be possible to undock to new window and drag it to another area, where the content will be tabbed to already existing content. It should be even possible to drop that window relative to any area so new area will appear. I already implemented this in Qt Widgets and i am fine to do this in C++ with Qt Quick 2, but not sure how to think in QML.

Comment: This is trivial to do with QML. My project is also an IDE, but the language is not typed but visual. I can split as many views as I want, from any root item I want, have some nodes hidden in one view but visible in another, have objects drawn in a different way or with different UIs in a view, pin objects from the view to any toolbar or have them free floating on the screen. I actually barely use stock QML components, QML is rather free form, you can pretty much do whatever you want with it. It is as simple as a parent/child tree, and a few expressions to define the layout and behavior.

Comment: @ddriver: is your app on github or any repo?

Comment: No, it is not public for the time being. I've posted some QML snippets and hacks here on SO in my answers.